# C# Authy RegisterUser fails

Tags: c#, authy

Here is what I've tried:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yJlQBd

the value of "authyKey" = the "Api Key for Production" found on the Dashboard.

When the code is run, the result:

registerUserResult.Message = "Invalid API key"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

"test: true" for testing, but needs to be "test: false" for production ... fixed